# completeness of measure space vs. completeness of normed space

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces

What is the relation between completeness in a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$  (i.e. every subset of a nullset is measurable, i.e. in $\mathcal{A})$ and completeness in a normed space $(X, \lVert\cdot\rVert)$  (i.e. every Cauchy sequence in $X$ has a limit in $X)$?

I am unable to make that link. Thank you for your help!

My question is very much like [this question without an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945174/completeness-of-metric-space-and-measure-space).

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990662/completeness-of-measure-spaces) people are saying the two concepts are unrelated without reasoning, which seems strange to me.

My try:

By definition, every Cauchy sequence in $X$ has a limit in $X$ means if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $X$ s.t. for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $n_0(\varepsilon)$ with $\lVert x_n-x\rVert<\varepsilon$ for $m,n\ge n_0(\varepsilon)$, then there exists some $x\in X$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\lVert x_n\to x\rVert=0$.

Now I think, that I should somehow link the norm to the measure...

From an other perspective, on [Wikipedia: Complete metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) it says:

> Intuitively, a space is complete if there are no "points missing"
>   from it (inside or at the boundary). For instance, the set of rational
>   numbers is not complete, because e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ is "missing" from it, even
>   though one can construct a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers that
>   converges to it. It is always possible to "fill all the holes", leading to the
>   completion of a given space.

Missing points would be subsets of a nullset. Now, if these points are not in $\mathcal{A}$, the limit $x\in X$ might not exist.

But if the measure space is complete, these missing points, subsets of nullsets are measurable and thus in the sigma-algebra and the limit always exists.

(Not a satisfactory argument, seems very handwaving to me.)